# This Javascript used to work, but now it doesn't

Tags: javascript, email, spam-prevention

I've had this Javascript code on my web site for years and it worked.  It is written to help filter out email spam bots;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
emailserver = "website.com" emailE = "Maria@" + emailserver document.write("<A href=" + "'mailto:" + emailE + "'>" + emailE + "</a>")
</script>
```

It hasn't worked for a while.  Can anyone tell me what changed so that this no longer works?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Works fine. You just forgot about semicolons `;`.

By the way, you don't need the quotation marks `"` in the last line of your code (in the `document.write()` function).

```js
emailserver = "website.com";
emailE = "Maria@" + emailserver;
document.write("<a href=" + "mailto:" + emailE + ">" + emailE + "</a>")
```